# Create a Automatic script to upload files in google cloud storage

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, google-bucket

I create a script to automatically upload my files to google cloud storage, my vm is in the same project as my Google Cloud Bucket...
So I create this script but I can't run it properly

```
#!/bin/bash
TIME=`date +%b-%d-%y`
FILENAME=backup-$TIME.tar.gz
SRCDIR=opt/R
DESDIR= gsutil gs cp FILENAME -$TIME.tar.gz  gs://my-storage-name
tar -cpzf $DESDIR/$FILENAME $SRCDIR
```

any help?

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: I suggest reviewing how to upload an object using `gsutil`: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#gsutil

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
TIME=`date +%b-%d-%y`
FILENAME=backup-$TIME.tar.gz
gsutil cp {path of the source-file} gs://my-storage-name/backup-$TIME.tar.gz
```

It will save your file with the name of backup-$TIME.tar.gz

> eg.backup-Jun-09-21.tar.gz